# Licensing of template code

Tags: software, open-source-software

GitHub has template repositories, that make it easy to offer starter code for new projects. I want to allow anyone to generate their projects from my template and then change the license to whatever they want. They should completely own their project. What kind of licensing would allow that? My current plan would be CC0. Would that work?